# Java profiling - detect what causes a spike

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, profiling, profiler, jvisualvm

I am trying to to detect what causes massive spikes in our Java struts bases web application deployed in Jboss. I have used Yourkit and visualVM to take dumps and have analysed dumps but these spikes are momentary and by the time the dump is taken nothing remains.

Question is - is there a way to detect what is causing a spike in the runtime?

Comment: Check what operations are getting performed by your app when you see spike..

Comment: when GC runs there are chances of spike. Check that.

Comment: What kind of spikes are you referring to? CPU usage?

Comment: Heap Memory spike - which means large objects or numerous objects are getting created. CPU is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most likely garbage collection can cause such an issue, I'd recommend enabling the garbage collection logging in the JVM using these command line options:

- `-Xloggc:<path and filename to log to>`
- `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry did you mean turning these ON will have an adverse effect on performance in the Live app?

Comment: @Soumya no, sorry if it was not clear. Though GC logging might need some disk IO, I don't think turning them on would make any significant performance issues. I rephrased the answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ideas:

- Examine your request logs to see if there is any correlation with the spikes and either request volumes or specific request types.
- Run the JVM with GC logging enabled and look for correlations.
- Enable your debug-level logging in your application and look for correlations.  (Be cautious with this one because turning on more application logging could change performance characteristics.)
- (On Linux / Unix) run vmstat and iostat and look for correlations with extra disc activity or swapping/paging.

---

If you have a spike in the object creation rate or in the number / size of non-garbage objects, this is most likely caused by your application rather than the JVM or operating system.  There is a good chance that it is due to a transient change in the nature of the application's workload; e.g. it is getting a spike in the requests, or it there is some unusual request that involves creating a lot of objects.  Focus on the request and application logs.

Comment: It's a Windows machine. Yes I guess I can turn on more logging in the application to see what is happening at that time. However the application has several pages and modules - all being used at the same time. So it's a bit tedious doing it that way. I was looking for tool that I can inject into the application which can log when some thread tries to create a lot of objects... or something in that line. Easier said than done probably :(